# Python Tracking change in values across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a certain scenario where I have a dataset with historical records and need to be able to flag if the latest entry for a certain ID is different than the last entry.

For example here is an example snapshot of starter df:

| ID | A | B | C | Close Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 10-1-2021 |
| 111 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 11-1-2021 |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 12-1-2021 |
| 222 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9-1-2021 |
| 222 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10-1-2021 |
| 333 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8-1-2021 |
| 333 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 12-1-2021 |

which I want to look like :

| ID | A | B | C | Close Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 12-1-2021 |
| 333 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 12-1-2021 |

Where entries without change are deleted and entries with some type of change in any of the given columns are different and the most recent record is kept according to most recent date.

I have tried this code:

df = df[df[['ID', 'A','B', 'C', 'Close Date']].duplicated() == False]

but realized that this does not fully capture all cases of this condition. Is there an easier way to compare if the latest entry is different from the previous ones per ID?

Edit:

What if the table were to have a mix of integer and string columns?

| ID | A | B | C | D | Close Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 | 1 | 0 | abcd | 10-1-2021 |
| 111 | 0 | 1 | 0 | efgh | 11-1-2021 |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ijkl | 12-1-2021 |
| 222 | 0 | 0 | 0 | mnop | 9-1-2021 |
| 222 | 0 | 0 | 0 | qrst | 10-1-2021 |
| 333 | 0 | 0 | 0 | uvwx | 8-1-2021 |
| 333 | 0 | 1 | 1 | yzzz | 12-1-2021 |

How then would I be able to check if the last two entries for each ID are the same? and if they are, to delete all instances of that ID.

Comment: " if the latest entry for a certain ID is different than the last entry." ?  Can you restate or clarify?

Comment: Yes certainly. I am just trying to compare if there was a change with that ID from the last entry. Lets say each date is a new month. So if the info from october for a person (ID) is the same  as November, this is no change and we delete this record. If the data in November for this person is different, this is a change that I want to track and keep in the df. Let me know if I can clarify more.

Comment: Could you update your dataframe sample to include `Close Date`? The example looks a little non-intuitive. Wouldn't you want to keep at least one record from the duplicated set? (like 111-0,1,0)

Comment: For my specific case I have a report that has logic to say if the record doesn't exist in the update, then there was no change. There is a record of it in a previous report which is why it doesn't matter in this case. I updated with Close Date

Comment: @ek11222 keeping that in mind I've tried out a solution that should work. See if it does the job for your entire dataset

Answer (score 1):

I think this gets you the output you want along with the original row number. Since you haven't provided column D I've used a list of columns to compare. Might help to sort via date if not already done. Might miss a few edge cases I think if there is only one entry for an ID, if you can update the example with problematic rows I can give it another look.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    [111, 0,1,0],
    [111, 0,1,0], 
    [111, 1,1,1], 
    [222, 0,0,0], 
    [222, 0,0,0], 
    [333, 0,0,0], 
    [333, 0,1,1] 
], 
columns=["ID", "A","B","C"])

cols_to_check = ["A","B", "C"]
res = df.groupby(
    'ID', as_index=False
  ).apply(
    lambda x: x[1:][(x[cols_to_check][1:] != x[cols_to_check].shift().dropna()).any(axis=1)])
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, this does work for the numerical columns and was very thorough. What would the case be if there were a mix of data types in the columns? Say for example, column A contains strings in each row and all other columns remain the same.

Comment: Well took me a bit to understand exactly but as I see it now the first row for any id would get dropped regardless. I've updated the answer, give it a try it should work for all cases. Drop the index if you don't want a multi-level dataframe.